# share internet from guest (kali linux) to host (Win10/Win7) using vmware

Tags: linux, networking, vmware

- My Host OS is Windows 10
- My Guest OS is Kali Linux
- Guest OS is installed on Vmware.

I connect Guest OS with internet using External WiFi Adapter. **This External WiFi Adapter can only work with any Linux OS.** My Host OS is Windows so I am not able to connect with internet using this External WiFi Adapter. My Guest OS easily connect with internet.

Now, I want to share Guest OS (Kali Linux) internet with Host OS (Win10/Win7)

Kindly guide me about the configuration of Guest OS, Host OS and Vmware

Comment: *"I want to share Guest OS (Kali Linux) internet with Host OS (Win10/Win7)"* - This makes no sense. If the guest has internet access, the host does as well. Please [edit] your question to clarify what exactly the problem you are attempting to solve is.

Comment: I updated my statements. The drivers of external wifi adapter is only available for linux.